# Get Unique Values Using Advanced Filters Not Working?

Tags: vba, excel, advanced-filter

I have two sheets:

Sheet 2:

```
Column C
Supplier Name
A
A
B
B
C
```

Sheet 1 (Desired Result)

```
Column G
A
B
C
```

I am trying to create a list of unique supplier names in column G on Sheet 1, as shown above.

I am using this code:

```
Sub LIST()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row

    Set r1 = Sheets("Data").Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16")

    r1.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=r2, unique:=True



End Sub
```

This code is not working correctly. It shows the first supplier name A as duplicated like so:

Sheet 1

```
Column G
A
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced Filter requires a header row that it carries across in a Copy To operation. Since you have not assinged or included one, the `r1.AdvancedFilter` command assumes that C2 is the header row.

Change `Range("C2:C" & lastrow)` to `Range("C1:C" & lastrow)` so that Advanced Filter has a header row to carry across.

```
Sub LIST()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set r1 = Sheets("Data").Range("C1:C" & lastrow)
    Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G16")

    r1.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=r2, Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Note that you will be carrying C1 across to Sheet1!G16. Delete it if is not desired.

Alternate with direct value transfer and RemoveDuplicates instead of AdvancedFilter.

```
Sub nodupeLIST()
    Dim r1 As Range, lastrow As Long

    With Worksheets("Data")
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set r1 = .Range("C2:C" & lastrow)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("G16").Resize(r1.Rows.Count, 1)
            .Cells = r1.Value
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: but what if I do not want my header row copied across also?

Comment: There is no provision for Advanced Filter or AutoFilter not to have a header row. Delete it from G16 or build a dictionary of unique keys and transfer the array of keys to G16. Maybe copy the whole thing across and RemoveDuplicates. There are other alternatives.