# Filter list unique value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter to get a unique range. a sample range as picture.

data input

[image]

I used this code

```
Sub main()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Spec")

ws.Range("A" & 1, "F" & 6).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ws.Range("H1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

but it return a wrong results below:
result

[image]

My expected result is here:

[image]

Comment: Please add the expected result if possible to clarify the question.

Comment: I have updated my question, please have a look my post again. thanks a lot

Comment: I want to have new range contains only unique row values

Comment: Hello, I believe you are bit by this header row issue:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940366/get-unique-values-using-advanced-filters-not-working

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have posted.  Your code and your data returns the four unique rows to the `H1` range. (O-365).