# Unique function in vba not working properly

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find the unique values in Column A and paste them into Column B. The code works for all values except the first value. For example see the table below. Column A contains the original values and Column B should contain the unique values.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | **AAA** |
| AAA | **AAA** |
| AAB | AAB |
| AAC | AAC |
| AAB |  |
| AAA |  |

The first value appears twice intead of just once. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code. ws2 is the sheet and LR2 is the last row in column A

```
ws2.Range("A2:A" & LR2).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("B2"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42940366/get-unique-values-using-advanced-filters-not-working